How to Decrypt a 7zip Encrypted Archive with a Forgotten Password
I have encrypted a folder using 7zip utility, I have used a strong password and the encrypting method is by default set to AES-256. Now I don't remember the exact password offcourse but i do remember most of the words i used in the password. I tried many ways to unsuccessfully decrypt the archive.
Possible Structure of Password:
I remember using following words and one special character in password. the first character of each word is capital, and the password was combined by special character i.e. _
XY99 Document or Documents Passphrase Folder _
following are the examples of what the password might look like but offcourse i have tried all of the possible combinations.
XY99_Folder_Documents
XY99_Folder_Documents_Passphrase
Folder_Documents_Passphrase_XY99
Folder_Documents_Passphrase
Documents_Passphrase_XY99_Folder
XY99_Folder_Documents_Passphrase
what i have tried so far
I used 7z2hashcat.pl to extract hash of 7zip archive. also wrote a python script which generates all the possible combinations and save it to wordlist.txt
import itertools

# Define the words to use in the password
words = ["XY99", "Folder", "Documents", "Passphrase"]
special_char = "_"

# Open the masks.hcmask file to write the combinations
with open("wordlist.txt", "w") as file:
    # Generate and write single word combinations
    for word in words:
        file.write(word + "\n")

    # Generate and write two-word combinations
    for combo in itertools.permutations(words, 2):
        file.write(special_char.join(combo) + "\n")

    # Generate and write three-word combinations
    for combo in itertools.permutations(words, 3):
        file.write(special_char.join(combo) + "\n")

    # Generate and write four-word combinations
    for combo in itertools.permutations(words, 4):
        file.write(special_char.join(combo) + "\n")

print("wordlist file has been generated.")

Then i used hashcat to execute following command.
hashcat -m 11600 -a 0 -o found.txt hash.txt wordlist.txt

Now i don't remember using anything between the password, and the method above is not working, any suggestions please
